# Nginx tens of thousands of domains with SSL in virtual host configuration. failed to initialize Lua VM, 4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory

Tags: nginx

Error:

```
nginx: [error] failed to initialize Lua VM in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:45
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
```

============================================================
nginx.conf

```
user httpd;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    #############################################
    # Basic Settings
    #############################################
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    map_hash_bucket_size 128;
    server_names_hash_max_size 512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    server_tokens off;
    more_set_headers "Server:"
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

        ############################################
        # core configuration files
        ############################################    
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

        #############################################
    # Virtual Host Configs
        #############################################
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* has 10k domains

==================================================
example configuration:

## /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com awatson.domain.com bbearman.domain.com bbearman2.domain.com jdoe.domain.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/letsencrypt-staging-full/20170428_154022/www.domain.com/www.domain.com_0_20170428_154022.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/letsencrypt-staging-full/20170428_154022/www.domain.com/www.domain.com_0_20170428_154022.key;
    include include/common.conf;
}
```

==================================================

## nginx version (debian 8):

```
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt=-Wl,-z,relro --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/ngx-fancyindex --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/nginx-http-push --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/nginx-lua --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/nginx-AGNHOe/nginx-1.6.2/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

==================================================

## Questions:

How can I make Nginx offload these many SSL domains (servers). I use LetsEncrypt, in order to handle subdomains SAN's are used. Most domains have naked and www domain. Some have 100 Subject alternative names. Should be able to handle this amount of domains easily, HAProxy does just fine.

Certs are valid, the configuration is fine with correct syntax. Scripted install, the scale does not change syntax or errors. Even using the same domain 10k times causes this error. Works with 500 domains just fine. Please only reply if you can solve the scaled example of tens of thousands of domains. I tried to install the latest version of Nginx as well. Same error. Help is appreciated.